# WPF Window with AllowsTransparency - bug with behind window

Tags: wpf, graphics, window, transparency

I use a window as a popup, with AllowsTransparency = "True".
This popup is shown in the middle of the screen.

The behing window, currently show a "loading" animation (this animation is a specific user control).

When the popup window is shown, there is a little bug : whe can see the animation blinking, as if the popup window render a transparency with the behind window animation (but just the animation), but not totally (causing this kind of blink)...

I use windows XP, and I wonder if it's a non-hardware acceleration issue :/

Comment: What's the kind of Dialogs !! Try Both Show() && ShowDialog() ..,

Comment: It's ShowDialog(), but I figured out that even with some splashscreens of programs (like the blend installation screen), the problem remains the same.

So the problem is targeted to the background window and how the animation user control is implemented...
I'll try to find out why i'm getting this issue